# Formatting time() in PHP

Tags: php, time, format

I'm using a database where in the table I have the time after it was saved using `time()`
Is there any way formatting it to human readable way (date and time)?

Thanks

Comment: There are a few examples in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you can use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for that.

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $timestamp);
```

Output will be in following format:

```
// March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
```

Answer (score 1):

you use this query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%M %d, %Y %h:%i:%s %p') as mydate
```

see [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Check here

[PHP Date() Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

There's a table with every option

An example:

```
date('Y m d')
```

prints

```
2013 07 19
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have trouble with the data displaying from some of the other answers there is also this function strtotime which may help parse it.

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

After querying the database for the timestamp, pass it through the function formatTime. This creates a new DateTime object in php called $data that can also easily be manipulated if you need. The examples below formats the date in two different ways, both work.

**Procedural Style:**

```
function formatTime($millis) { 
        $date = new DateTime($millis); 
        return date_format($date, 'l, jS F Y \a\t g:ia'); 
}
```

**Object Oriented Style:**

```
function formatTime($millis) { 
        $date = new DateTime($millis); 
        return $date->format('l, jS F Y \a\t g:ia'); 
}
```

The format for date can be found at this link: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Cheers!